# Its possible create a trigger after every transact in all DB? (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql-server, trigger, logon-trigger

I have 100+ databases in my instace of SQL SERVER and mostly is a legacy DB but i dont have a control of what is new and what is old.

My idea is create a Trigger in all server for every transact and INSERT in table for audit.

I create this table on master:

```
CREATE TABLE Audit_Logins
    (Login_Name NVARCHAR(256), 
     Login_Time DATETIME,
     Db_name NVARCHAR(100),
     Host_Name  NVARCHAR(200)
    );
```

And try create a trigger on LOGON for store this information

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_log_on_logon ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
        DECLARE @login NVARCHAR(200);
        DECLARE @db NVARCHAR(100);
        SET @login = ORIGINAL_LOGIN();
        SET @db = DB_NAME();
        IF(@login LIKE '%domain%' AND @db <> NULL)
     BEGIN
           INSERT INTO Audit_Logins
                SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), 
                       GETDATE(),
                       DB_NAME(),
             EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(128)');
     END
```

But this doesnt work, if i run a select or any other command not fire the trigger.

Comment: May be it's because a logon trigger fires only upon logon? Besides, queries (`select` statements) never trigger anything. Looks like what you want is [audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I understand, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that SQL triggers are the best tool for this job, I'd encourage you to look into the variety of SQL's auditing-related features, or look into 3rd-party SQL auditing tools:

- [SQL Server Auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [SQLShack Blog: Various techniques to audit SQL Server databases](https://www.sqlshack.com/various-techniques-to-audit-sql-server-databases/)
- [MSSQLTips Blog: SQL Server Auditing Tools](https://www.mssqltips.com/sql-server-tool-category/4/auditing/)

Comment: I'll give you a read, thank you very much